# Regex incorrectly evaluating true

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to validate at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase and one digit. So far I have:

```
"orange" -match "(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*"
False
```

Good

```
"Orange22" -match "(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*"
True
```

Good

```
"orange22" -match "(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*"
True
```

Bad - no uppercase letter but still a match.

What is wrong with the regex example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell regex is case insensitive by default.  Instead of using `-match` use `-cmatch`:

```
"orange22" -cmatch "(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*"
```

Comment: To add more information, as Tim stated comparison operators are case insensitive, but you can extend the relationship between `-match` and `-cmatch` to any comparison operator. `-ceq` case-sensitively compares strings, `-clike` case-sensitively does a wildcard compare, etc. Basically, you can take any comparison operator, prefix it with a `c`, and it becomes case-sensitive.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I guess I `c` what you mean LOL :P